# Cypress unable to click on hidden element from mouseover dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, cypress

I'm having trouble writing a test case in Cypress on clicking the "Log out" button because it's hidden unless hovering over the "Settings" button. I've tried setting the click method to {force: true} but wasn't successful in actually clicking the button in my test case. Any suggestions?

Test Case:

```
// Validates logging out
it('Logging out', function() {
    cy.get('.menuLink').contains('Settings').trigger('mouseover');
    cy.get('div[class="submenusWrapper svelte-1c7tfr1"]').contains('Log out').invoke('show').click();
});
```

[image: HTML Snippet]

[image: Cypress Error]

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [cypress real events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) plugin. Then in your test write:

```js
cy.contains('.menuLink','Settings').realHover()
cy.contains('.submenu','Log out').click()
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried this and it worked. Much appreciated